# How to have Django raise ValidationError as Popup?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am using a custom `clean()` function on one of my forms for a conditional field requirement. I am able to raise the validation error on my template as a part of the DOM using `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. I would like to have the validation error come up as a popup like the default errors do, but do not know how.

Here is the custom `clean()` function:

```py
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        class_type = cleaned_data.get("class_type")
        class_other = cleaned_data.get("class_other")
        if class_type == "Other":
            if not class_other:
                msg = "Please fill out this field."
                raise ValidationError(msg)
```

I don't know what to put in views or the template to have it show as a popup - I don't currently have anything special there. Is it possible with Django, or do I need to use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

By "popup window", you are probably referring to the alert box. Browsers generate it when the user attempts to submit a form with an uncompleted html required input. You can add the required field like this:

```py
    class BasicForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(
            max_length = 35, 
            widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    "id" : "name",
                    "class" : "input-class",
                    "placeholder" : "Insert Your Name",
                    "required" : "required", # <--- HERE YOU GO
                }
            )
        )
```

You can force the browser to generate an alertbox even when the form is filled with javascript. For example:

```js
btn = document.getElementById("button");
inp = document.getElementById("name");

// this piece of code will wait for the user to 
// release a keyboard button having the input#name focused
// then will call the function
inp.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  // I get the input value
  current_name = inp.value;
  // Checking if the name is longer than 8 characters
  if (current_name.length > 8) {
    // I will open an alert box
    alert("Your name is too long!");
  }
});

// this piece of code will wait for the user to 
// click on the input#button, then will 
// clear the input
btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
  // Clearing the input value
  inp.value = "";
});
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="input-class" required>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="clear"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't/didn't want to set the field as required in the form, because it is only required under certain circumstances. I ended up using js create/remove the form field on the page based on the "certain circumstances" and add mark it required as necessary.